# Looking to prevent users from changing lead status manually as a process builder is already in place

Tags: process-builder, validation-rule

I am looking to stop users from manually changing the lead status to both "working-attempted" and "working-contacted" as we currently have a process builder in place that automates this based on certain parameters.  Can anyone help with what the validation rule logic should look like.  Especially in regards to allowing the process builder to bypass this validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting need. I *think* the only way to accomplish this would be to remove the options altogether as I can't think of a good solution using validation rules.

If you set those values to inactive they will be unavailable for users but should still be available for the PB.

### Update

Ran a quick test and standard lead status field is not strictly enforced which means the above solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

Better create lead recortype and assign only desired values in picklist. So user will not able to see those values during create or edit in page layout. Since process builder runs in system mode so those values can be updated by that. You can also update this recordtype through field update.

The above solution is an alternative to validation rule.

Comment: I was hoping to still be able to display those values in the "Lead Path", ideally when they were selected an error message would appear